# Predicate on to-many relationship

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

I have a managed object reference *event.

An Event has many Occurrences. An Occurrence has an attribute call `date`

I want to fetch all the occurrences of the event *event which has today's date. How should I write a NSPredicate on a FetchRequest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be aware, that there are two ways to get your Occurrence objects: You can traverse the relationship from the Event object (i.e. `myEvent.occurences`) or you can create a fetch request for all occurrences that have the event of interest in their inverse relationship, i.e. a predicate like `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"event == %@", myEvent"]`.

There are fundamental differences to these two. A fetch request will **always** cause SQL to be executed and I/O to happen which is expensive. If you simply traverse the relationship, *and* you're in a situation where the Occurrence objects are already in memory, it will be very cheap to do (no SQL, no I/O). The fetch request on the other hand, will allow you to fault in all objects in one go, while traversing will only fault objects one at a time, so you'll end up doing multiple SQL + I/O events. Also, a fetch request allows you to limit the predicate even further. But in many cases, simply traversing might be the best case.

CoreData does a lot of heavy lifting for you, but at the end of the day, you still need to know about when to do SQL and I/O and how to prevent it.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the construction of the predicate to filter out the event which occurs today.

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]

                         initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *components =[gregorian components:(NSDayCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit)  fromDate:today];
[components setHour:0];
[components setMinute:0];
[components setSecond:0];
NSDate *todayMidnight=[gregorian dateFromComponents:components];
#define Hours_24 86400
NSDate *tomorrowMidnight=[NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:Hours_24 sinceDate:todayMidnight];
NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"occurance.date >= %@ AND occurance.date< %@",todayMidnight,tomorrowMidnight];
[gregorian release];
```

Since the attribute of `occurance` is of `NSDate` datatype, it will have the time as well as the date. So, this predicate will filter out all `occurances` whose date falls between today midnight and tomorrow midnight. Another way(and better, in my opinion), would be to get the `Occurances` and then do the filtering.
Don't forget to `setPropertiesToFetch`: to `occurance` if you want only the `occurance` and not the event. This will return an `NSDictionary`.